# Remove Drop Down Box from Column Headers

Tags: 2010, jquery, list-view, column, header

I'm using SharePoint 2010.  Does anyone know a way to remove all of the properties/events from the column headers `(th)` so that it just displays the column name on a view?

I'm trying to create a printable view that doesn't have the dropdown boxes on the header fields.  I'd rather stick with Jquery and not have to edit the page using SharePoint Designer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via CSS as the following:

- add script editor in your page > add this code

**[Code]**

```
 <style>
th .ms-core-menu-box, .ms-positionRelative
{
 display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

- Stop edit.
- Click on the header, you should note that there's no any functionality at columns header.

Also, check my article with the detail steps at [Hide Open Menu at ListView Header via CSS in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/11/08/hide-open-menu-listview-header-css-sharepoint/)